# Append a data frame to a list

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out how to add a data.frame or data.table to the first position in a list.

Ideally, I want a list structured as follows:

```
List of 4
 $  :'data.frame':  1 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ a: num 2
  ..$ b: num 1
  ..$ c: num 3
 $ d: num 4
 $ e: num 5
 $ f: num 6
```

Note the data.frame is an object within the structure of the list.

The problem is that I need to add the data frame to the list after the list has been created, and the data frame has to be the first element in the list. I'd like to do this using something simple like `append`, but when I try:

```
append(list(1,2,3),data.frame(a=2,b=1,c=3),after=0)
```

I get a list structured:

```
str(append(list(1,2,3),data.frame(a=2,b=1,c=3),after=0))
List of 6
 $ a: num 2
 $ b: num 1
 $ c: num 3
 $  : num 1
 $  : num 2
 $  : num 3
```

It appears that R is coercing data.frame into a list when I'm trying to `append`. How do I prevent it from doing so? Or what alternative method might there be for constructing this list, inserting the data.frame into the list in position 1, after the list's initial creation.

Comment: Richard, This is not what I am trying to do. I am trying to add an object to a list that is already defined. Yes, I could redefine the whole list, but I was hoping not to need to do that. What I would like to do is to insert an object into a list with as little trouble as possible. The list is rather long and I would rather not restructure the whole list that way.  I do see your point on the use of append as being designed for vectors, but it seems like there should be a corresponding function for lists, no?

Comment: That does it! Could you move your comment to an answer so I can mark it as selected?

Comment: A better title might be "prepend to list" or something. This doesn't seem related to data.table in particular, nor really appending.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The issue you are having is that to put a data frame anywhere into a list as a single list element, it must be wrapped with `list()`.  Let's have a look.

```
df <- data.frame(1, 2, 3)
x <- as.list(1:3)
```

If we just wrap with `c()`, which is what `append()` is doing under the hood, we get

```
c(df)
# $X1
# [1] 1
#
# $X2
# [1] 2
#
# $X3
# [1] 3
```

But if we wrap it in `list()` we get the desired list element containing the data frame.

```
list(df)
# [[1]]
#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  1  2  3
```

Therefore, since `x` is already a list, we will need to use the following construct.

```
c(list(df), x) ## or append(x, list(df), 0)
# [[1]]
#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  1  2  3
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 1
#
# [[3]]
# [1] 2
#
# [[4]]
# [1] 3
```

Comment: This worked very well. Thanks. FWIW it also seems to play nice with data.table too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me out. 

In my case, I wanted to assign a data frame to a list with a specific code but faced the similar issue. For those who face the same issue as me, you can refer to this approach as well.

```my_list <- list();
my_data_frame <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = 3:4);
my_list["my"] <- list(my_data_frame);```